# Oozie fork call same action multiple times

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to run multiple instances of same oozie action in parallel using fork. While trying to do so, I duly got error stating

> "E0744" A fork is not allowed to have multiple transitions to the same node

I looked at the oozie codebase as well (*LiteWorkflowAppParser*) and found out oozie is indeed not allowing run call same action multiple times in fork as it validates for that. Now I disabled the validation using `oozie.wf.validate.ForkJoin=false` and ran the workflow again. This time, the workflow is running fine, but only one instance of the action is running. To me, it seems like though I have disabled validation, oozie underneath lets only unique actions to run, and duplicate actions are skipped. 
Now my question is, how can I achieve running multiple oozie actions in parallel?

My workflow is like:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="my-workflow">
   <start to="parallelize"/>
   <fork name="parallelize">
      <path start="performAction" />
      <path start="performAction" />
      <path start="performAction" />
   </fork>
<action name="performAction">
.......
  <ok to="joinForks"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<join name="joinForks" to="end" />
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Responder Application, error
        message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
    </message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

**Additional details:**
With the above configuration, I see that the workflow is stuck after completion of `performAction` in transition to `joinForks` stage. It looks like the `joinForks` is waiting for remaining actions to report to it so that it can end. But the problem is, the remaining actions were never launched, resulting in workflow waiting indefinitely.

After this, I just copied `performAction` into three different actions `performAction1`, `performAction2`, `performAction3` and used them in the forks. Now the workflow is completing as `joinForks` gets called from all the forks. But still, I really wish I don't have to do this workaround of duplicating the same action again and again under different name. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your workflow / config file.

Comment: @codeaperature provided sample workflow file. Thanks for taking look at it

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the error message you're getting is because of this code:

```
<fork name="parallelize">
  <path start="performAction" />
  <path start="performAction" />
  <path start="performAction" />
</fork>

<action name="performAction">
  ...
  <ok to="joinForks"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

I suspect the forks must be uniquely named, like this:

```
<fork name="parallelize">
  <path start="performAction1" />
  <path start="performAction2" />
  <path start="performAction3" />
</fork>
<action name="performAction1"> 
  ...
  <ok to="joinForks"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<action name="performAction2">
  ...
  <ok to="joinForks"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<action name="performAction3"> 
  ...
  <ok to="joinForks"/>
  <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

It seems that having 3 forks with the same name is throwing off the uniquely named requirement for transitions.

Can you try the uniquely-named individual forks instead?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. As I mentioned in the additional notes, this was indeed working for me to add multiple actions with different names. I just wanted to do without duplication though. Let me know if you have any ideas on how can I achieve that. May be declare a common module and inherit that in each actions?

Comment: I think that's impossible, the actions should have unique naming

Comment: @mangusta Yes that is true. Hence what I thought of doing is, define the body of action (spark action) as some section and import that section inside multiple actions so that I can prevent duplicating that section. But I don't know how to define it.

Comment: @sriram you may have a look at oozie "subworkflow" concept, although I'm not sure if that is exactly what you're looking for. "subworkflow" is used to call a part of workflow that repeats multiple times in the main workflow, i.e. similar to a function or method or procedure in the programming language. it allows to significantly shorten and thus simplify the main workflow

Comment: @mangusta Yes sub workflows are the way to go. I referred other examples as well. This case is implemented as sub workflows. Thanks for getting back.